# Execute JSP at Tomcat Startup

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, rhel

Please note that I am not the developer of this app and I realize that there are probably better ways to implement it.  However, I have been given the following objective:

I need to automatically execute a jsp page when tomcat starts on an RHEL server.  The only kicker is that their are three URL Parameters that need to be passed.

Here is an example of the URL:

http://www.myurl.com/app/getlistdata.jsp?param1=P1&param2=P2&param3=P3

In my web.xml I have the following but it does not seem to be loading automatically.  I suppose I could modify the start_tomcat script to include a wget but I was hoping to make this independent from the server it is deployed to.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>getlistdata</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/getlistdata.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>param1</param-name>
            <param-value>P1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>param2</param-name>
            <param-value>P2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>param3</param-name>
            <param-value>P3</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to find a solution to the above problem, I'd rather do some refactoring... In case you cannot do this, just create some scripts. Btw: Init attributes are **not** request parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution used was to add a curl command to the startup_tomcat script.

```
URL="http://SOMEURL.COM/GOES/HERE"
nohup curl $URL >> /home/tomcat/log &
exit
```

While there are many technical reasons not to do this, it met the business requirements that were provided.

Answer (score 2):

As @home said - Init attributes are not request parameters - so which do you mean? JSPs are used to render a view to a browser as a response to a request. Doing that when Tomcat starts up makes no sense because there's no request.

Look at the JSP. Perhaps it uses a Java Bean under the hood to do some processing. If you can move this processing out to a Context Listener, that would work:

In your web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    path.to.YourListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

And then create a java class:

```
public class YourListener implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // this will execute when tomcat initialized the web application (on startup)
    // so whatever your JSP was doing, you can do in here instead.
  }
}
```

Not quite what you asked for, but this is the closest you can do, AFAIK.